# Get default theme for TextFormField's InputDecoration's label

Tags: flutter

I need to create a custom widget that sits alongside of `TextFormField`s, so I have to style its label to match `TextFormField`'s label style.

This does NOT work:

```
Theme.of(ctx).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle
```

Because, according to its doc:

> If null, defaults to a value derived from the base [TextStyle] for the
>   input field and the current [Theme].

The problem is, I don't know how to get that base style.

Comment: `Theme.of(ctx).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle` is working completely fine for me. What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: @KeertiPurswani I need to get the font color and size. When you said "working completely fine", did you try putting a breakpoint and see whether the value is `null`? It is for my case.

Comment: I can see the text in label's font color and size. Where and why would I put breakpoint and check?

Comment: @KeertiPurswani try the `errorStyle`, which should be red. It does not end up being red because `errorStyle` is `null`, which defaults to the base `TextStyle` as described in the question

Comment: @KeertiPurswani ThemeData.fallback().inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle => null and also Theme.of(buildContext).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle=> null  on flutter 2.2.3 running on android

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the base style correctly. In my case `labelStyle` and `hintStyle` from `InputDecorationTheme` can not be updated by **hot reload**, but they work when **rerunning** the app.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a complete answer but I have found the color is based on the primarySwatch color. If you are using light theme, just define the primarySwatch and it will do it. For dark theme:

```
ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark, 
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
              primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue, // use your material color
              brightness: Brightness.dark)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the base without having to declare it in your theme data just instance an empty TextStyle and flutter will do the job